# Typescript : AngularJS retrieving a result object

Tags: angularjs, typescript

I have a AngularJS service in Typescript that makes a get https call returns some data. 
My results is a child object of the `response.data` as follows `response.data.Result`.

How do I get access to it? I cannot do `response.data.Result` as I get compile time error where the `response.data` defined under `IHttpPromiseCallbackArg<T>` does not have the result property.

```
 class ApplicationService implements IApplicationService {
        private webApiUrl;
        static $inject = ['$http'];

        constructor(private $http: ng.IHttpService) {
            this.webApiUrl = 'http://localhost';
            this.$http = $http;
        }

        getApplications(): ng.IPromise<IApplication[]> {
            return this.$http.get(this.webApiUrl + '/api/applications')
                .then((response: ng.IHttpPromiseCallbackArg<IApplication[]>): IApplication[]=> {
                return <IApplication[]>response.data;
            });
        }
    }
```

Comment: Print `response`. What does it show?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

After `this.$http.get(this.webApiUrl + '/api/applications')`, try changing from `ng.IHttpPromiseCallbackArg<IApplication[]>` to `{ data: { Result: IApplication[] } }` type.

```
class ApplicationService implements IApplicationService {
    private webApiUrl;
    static $inject = ['$http'];

    constructor(private $http: ng.IHttpService) {
        this.webApiUrl = 'http://localhost';
        this.$http = $http;
    }

    getApplications(): ng.IPromise<IApplication[]> {
        return this.$http.get(this.webApiUrl + '/api/applications')
        .then((response: { data: { Result: IApplication[] } }): IApplication[]=> {
            return response.data.Result;
        });
    }
}
```